# Lower_bound vs binary search

Tags: binary-search, std

I was learning some [STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) functions and I came across this function
[lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) .I am in a confusion that why doesn't people use **lower_bound** instead of **binary search** as both do the same thing ,both of them have  O(log n) complexity.

Isn't it better to write just one line code with lower_bound than 8-9 lines of if-else statements with binary search or is their any limitation of lower_bound that I didn't know about because of which people don't use it often?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`binary_search` is (IMO) poorly named. It tells you via a binary search whether an item exists in your collection. It does not tell you where.

`lower_bound` tells you where the item should go in the collection, but does not actually verify that the item exists at that place in the collection. You need to check yourself (and be careful not to dereference the `end` iterator!).

[`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) tells you where the item should go, and (based on the distance between `first` and `second`) how many of the item actually exist in the range, or zero if the item doesn't exist. In my opinion it's the most useful. It's slightly slower than `lower_bound` but not by much.